# Explicación de la función Push

Tags: c++, lista, push

Antes de hacer la pregunta, quería decir que es mi primer topic en el foro entonces si erro en alguna norma, decirme por favor, también cualquier consejo es bienvenido.
Yendo al grano, mi problema se centra en la función Push (o agregarALaPila) que se maneja con pilas/stacks, que si bien se como se codifica, el razonamiento del mismo me cuesta un poco. Vamos con el código (no uso template, quiero aprenderlo primero para enteros, **int**):

```
void push(Node* &p, int v)
{
Node* aux = new Node(); //Creo un nodo que va ser unido a la pila
aux->info = v; //Agrego el dato al nodo
aux->sig = p;  //Hago que este nodo apunte a la pila
p = nuevo; // ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA 
}
```

Después de mucho razonarlo, e investigando, concluyo que este ultimo paso es para que, en el lugar donde apunta a la pila, ocupe dicho espacio igualándolo, y quedando asi el dato en el primer lugar. ¿Es correcto?

Slds! Y desde ya gracias!

Comment: Hola alevinas! Bienvenido a [es.so] un sitio de **preguntas y respuestas** para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas te recomiendo leer [ask] para recibir respuestas de calidad por parte de la comunidad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagina una pila de objetos, cada vez que añades uno nuevo a la pila, lo apilas en la parte superior; cuando tienes varios tu pila podría parecerse (conceptualmente) a esto:
[image]

En programación, los contenedores de datos (normalmente) no guardan el dato en crudo si no una estructura que envuelve el dato y describe la manera en que un dato se relaciona con el siguiente (esa estructura suele llamarse *Nodo*), en el caso de una pila la relación siempre es "*Todo dato nuevo se pondrá encima del dato anterior*".

La función que pones como ejemplo hace esa misma operación:

```
Node* aux = new Node();
aux->info = v;
aux->sig = p;
```

El código anterior, como ya has deducido, crea el nuevo nodo en el que guarda el dato (`v`, que va a parar a `Node::info`) y lo conecta con el nodo proveído por parámetro (`p` es guardado en `Node::sig`). Acto seguido:

```
p = aux;
```

Entiendo que tienes un error de transcripción en tu código pues la variable `nuevo` no existe, seguramente querías usar `aux`. Esa orden establece que el nodo proveído será el nuevo nodo creado.

---

Es difícil deducir más información del poco (y erróneo) código que has compartido, pero asumiendo que estés trabajando con una pila, la siguiente ilustración debería parecerse a las operaciones que (presuntamente) estás haciendo:

1. Partimos de esta situación inicial.

[image]

2. Se crea el nuevo nodo, al que se le asigna `v` y se le hace apuntar al mismo sitio que `p`.

[image]

3. Finalmente se hace que `p` apunte al nuevo nodo creado.

[image]

---

Si te fijas, conceptualmente estamos *apilando* nodos unos encima de otros. Ésto funciona así porque tanto la instrucción `aux->sig = p;` como la instrucción `p = nuevo;` opera sobre punteros. Los punteros en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y [c](/questions/tagged/c) son un tipo de datos que apunta a otros datos, así que la operación de apuntar un puntero a otro (`aux->sig = p;` y `p = nuevo;`) hace que ambos punteros apunten al mismo sitio (como se ha visto en la ilustración).

Comment: Sería genial si usted fuese mi profesor de estructuras de datos.

Comment: Ante todo muchas gracias Paula, respondiste a mi duda. Y si, pido perdón pero era p = aux, transcribí mal el código, es que hice la misma función varias veces y a veces utilicé 'aux' y en otras 'nuevo'. Además, si, el tratamiento de la función era sobre una pila, por ende la función que pasé era correcta, mi problema era entender la lógica. Muy didáctico y útil los graficos, thx.